Почему Google Apps Script снова и снова требует авторизации
WEB APP на основе Google Spreadsheet и GAS раньше нормально работал.
Позже Google стал строже учитывать свои ресурсы и пришлось создать Проект в Google Cloud Platform под это дело и указать его id в настройках скрипта.
C тех пор авторизация, которую я даю этому проекту на доступ к своим Sheets и Drive, стала коротко-живущей Из-за этого пользоваться становится невозможным.
Что нужно сделать, чтобы разрешения, которые я даю этому скрипту / проекту — не слетали?

Вот тут описано рабочее решение, посмотрите
https://t.me/googleappsscriptrc/74400
